# How do I run an older RDLC report on Windows 10

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I recently upgraded to Windows 10. As soon as we did, my project lost the ability to generate the RDLC reports. The RDLC files have worked properly for several years now with minimal modification. We are generating the reports from within our web app and displaying them with the ASP.Net WinForms report viewer control. Here is the code we use to generate the report.

```
    private LocalReport GenerateReport(LocalReport report, List<ReportParameter> parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
            var reportPath = Path.Combine(filePath, @"bin\FinalReport.rdlc");
            // if file doesn't exist, try an alternate path.  This is for development.
            if (!File.Exists(reportPath))
            {
                reportPath = Path.Combine(filePath, @"bin\Reports\FinalReport.rdlc");
            }
            report.ReportPath = reportPath;
            if (!File.Exists(report.ReportPath)) throw new FileLoadException(string.Format("Cannot find file {0} to load", report.ReportPath));
            report.SetParameters(parameters);
            report.Refresh();
            return report;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.Logger.Log(ex);
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while generating the report.", ex);
        }
    }
```

When I try to generate a report with the code "report.Refresh();", I get an exception that says: “The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.”

I assume this has something to do with needing to run the old version of the Microsoft.ReportViewer dlls. I made sure that I .Net 3.5 installed on the machine. (It is not installed by default with Windows 10). I made sure that the project reference to the Microsoft.ReportViewer dlls was set to the 10.0 version and had "specific version" set to true. But even when I do this, I still get the same exception.

Have you guys encountered this problem? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: The OS has nothing to do with the error - did you google the error? It's typically caused by incompatible report versions, eg trying to run a 2008 R2 report on 2008, or because local mode doesn't support the 2010 schema. Which Report Viewer version are you using? How were the reports created ? Why install .NET 3.5 anyway? Doesn't the application run with 4?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. I clarified my question a little bit. I am not generating the report inside of SQL Server, we are generating the report right in the web application. We I googled the error, all of the results had to do with running the reports inside of SQL Server. Nothing I could find with Google applied to my situation, even though the error messages were similar.

Comment: This didn't make anything clearer - the error is caused because you are trying to open an RDLC file with the 2010 schema on a ReportViewer that doesn't support it. Did you copy the wrong RV version perhaps? Did you switch from remote to local mode at some point? RV doesn't support 2010 on local mode.

Comment: To avoid confusion, create a minimal application *in .NET 4.5.2 or 4.6* and try to open a report. This will avoid issues with mismatched control and dll versions.